# Get mobile network frequency band Android

Tags: java, android, frequency, telephonymanager

I'm building an app for Android  witch logs some data about phone mobile network,

```
Access Type: (GPRS, 3G, HSPA, LTE)
Frequency: (WCDMA 2100 Band 1)
LAC: Location Area Code
SAC: Serving Area CellID (if 3G)
CGI: Cell Global Identifier (if 2G)
Signal level: –88dbm
```

So far i have managed to get everything by using Telephony manager,  except: Frequency: (`WCDMA 2100 Band 1`) there is not even a mention of mobile network Frequency as I saw.

Any way to get this data form android phone ???

Comment: did you find out the answer?

Answer (score 0):

try to dial *#0011# on your android phone

Answer (score 0):

In order to get some of the low level measurements made on the radio, you will need to utilize the Qualcomm libraries. This will require C++ development. Check out their site:

[Qualcomm Gobi 3G & 4G Modems](https://developer.qualcomm.com/discover/chipsets-and-modems/gobi-3g-4g-modems)